# overiding class attributes but not methods in the child class

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance

I have this problem, for example I define a `Vehicle` class as such.

```
class Vehicle():
    speed = 0
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def get_speed(self):
        return Vehicle.speed
```

I have a class attribute `speed` which I will override in the `Bike` child class

```
class Bike(Vehicle):
   speed = 20
```

if I instantiate a new object of type `Bike` I get this

```
>>> a = Bike()
>>> a.get_speed()
0
```

How do I make it to get without having to override parent class methods.

```
>>> a.get_speed()
20
```

I do have a solution but I don't know if it is a good programming practice or not, because instance variables should be unique to that instance, so now I am very much confused.

```
class Vehicle():
   def __init__(self):
      self.speed = 0

   def get_speed(self):
      return self.speed

class Bike(Vehicle):
   def __init__(self):
      self.speed = 20
```

should I re-declare it as an instance variable so that if I override `self.speed = 20` in the constructor then I get

```
>>> a = Bike()
>>> a.get_speed()
20
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Depends a little. Do all vehicles of the same class have the same speed in your design, or can let's say two bikes have different speeds?

Comment: All bikes have the same speed, I am going to make another subclass like car, where all cars have same speed maybe 30 for example, and thanks for commenting so fast by the way.

Comment: In that case, just change `return Vehicle.speed` to `return self.speed` and that's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need `get_speed` to be a class-wide property (not an instance-wide), you could use `@classmethod` decorator:

```
class Vehicle():
    speed = 0
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def get_speed(cls):
        return cls.speed
```

It would still be possible to override `speed` attribute inside a class instance though.

Comment: Thank you very much Pavel for answering so quickly.

Answer (score 3):

If an attribute cannot be found in an object's `__dict__`, i.e. when it is not an instance attribute, Python will look for that attribute in the class next.

That's why you can simply do:

```
>>> class Vehicle:
...     speed = 0
...     def get_speed(self):
...         return self.speed
...     
>>> class Bike(Vehicle):
...     speed = 20
...     
>>> a = Bike()
>>> a.get_speed()
20
```

Additionally, I would get rid of that `get_speed` method. Writing getters and setters is not idiomatic Python. Simply use `a.speed`.

If you want to protect the attribute against being set, consider using [properties](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_properties.php).

Comment: Thank you very much much timgeb, I'll go refactor my code.